# Angular CLI project not working after copying and pasting

Tags: node.js, git, angular

I'm new to Angular and over the past few days I've been creating a new project using it. I've used the Angular CLI to create the project and it's been running fine. I've added no additional dependencies or done anything special.

I want to upload my project to GIT, so I copied and pasted the contents of the project folder into another directory. Now when I attempt to run the project it doesn't work - I get the error:

```
Cannot get /
```

The project still works in its previous location. I've tried deleting node_modules and doing an npm install but still have the same problem.

I don't know what additional information to provide as I've not been using Angular long.

Comment: *"I want to upload my project to GIT"* - you mean GitHub? *"so I copied and pasted the contents of the project folder into another directory"* - why?

Comment: Well a Git Repository yes - not one hosted by GitHub. And I already had the repo cloned so I was copying my project into the repo folder on my machine.

Comment: The remote doesn't really matter, but the directory the CLI created is already a repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments here by jonrsharpe helped lead me to an answer. The problem isn't with the project itself (as such) but rather the folder/repository itself. Angular will throw the "Cannot get /" error when in a folding containing "%20" in it's name.